# HA / Distributed Zabbix Monitoring

Tags: monitoring, distributed, high-availability, zabbix

I am using [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) to monitor severall websites using Ping-Checks and HTTP-Service Checks on Port 80. Agent monitoring is not possible due to access rights. My Zabbix server is running on a virtual private server located in Frankfurt, Germany. Everything works fine. My hoster has to do some network hardware updates from time to time which leads to short network outages (~30 minutes) and so monitoring for this period of time is not possible. I planned to look for a seconds VPS at another data center and hosting provider and also started searching for a solution and found something about *Zabbix Nodes and Proxys*.

Is this the right way to go for me or is it some kind of overpower (its private)? For me it is important to have a ~1 year monitoring history of several websites without outages. I want both zabbix servers to gather monitoring data indepently and get this data merged together in nearly realtime. Maybe there is another solution which also works fine for my requirements? I thought about using a distributed MySQL database with two db nodes or so.

Answer (score 2):

Use active zabbix-agents and active zabbix-proxy! they save a data while connection lost.